# How to solve $f(-4)$ if $f(x)=\frac{x^3+64}{x+4}$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I need to solve $f(-4)$ if $f(x)=\frac{x^3+64}{x+4}$. I have changed the form of the function, but for some reason I'm still not getting the right answer.

**My Steps:**

$$\frac{x^3+64}{x+4}$$

apply $(a+b)^3=(a+b)(a^2+2ab+b^2)$ formula

$$=\frac{(x+4)(x^2+8x+16)}{x+4}$$

$$=x^2+8x+16$$

Insert $-4$ for $x$.

$$(-4)^2+8(-4)+16 = 16-32+16 = 0$$

Comment: It should be $x^2-4x+16$

Comment: @robjohn Whoops, my mistake!

Comment: f(-4) does not exist since strictly speaking we have $\dfrac{0}{0}$ which doesn't make sense in the world of real numbers. But if we allow $f$ to be redefined at that removable discontinuity, then we can have $f(-4)$ take a value upon cancellation of common factors.

Comment: $ x^3 +  4^3$ is not $(x + 4)^3$.  Try it with some simple values of $x$ such as $1$.

Comment: @badjohn Right, I keep forgetting that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no value $f(-4)$ since $-4$ is not in the domain of the function by mere fact of the division by zero that results. Even if the expression simplifies, it doesn't change the removable discontinuity being present.

In any event, if you want to find an almost-equivalent expression for $f$ that gets rid of the discontinuity, note that you factor a sum of two cubes as so:

$$a^3 + b^3= (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$$

(You made a sign error, thus why I noted it. In general, you might see this written as $a^3 \pm b^3 = (a \pm b)(a^2 \mp ab + b^2)$ to account for the sign change.)

Thus, $x^3 + 64 = x^3 + 4^3$ factors as

$$x^3 + 64 = (x+4)(x^2 - 4x + 16)$$

Then dividing by $(x+4)$ gives you $g(x) = x^2 - 4x + 16$. In this sense, you have $g(-4)$ defined.

Comment: EDIT: Fixed a few dumb errors regarding the factoring. It should have be $a^3 \pm b^3$ where applicable, not $(a \pm b)^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am still a bit confused though. I should've mentioned the problem description made it clear I would have to redefine the function. The thing is, $(-4)^2+4(-4)+16=16-16+16=16$ which is still apparently not the right answer. So, I feel like I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: The "redefining the function" thing is basically what I did in the problem, expressing it in terms of $g$ after "simplifying" $f$. In any event, you made a sign arrow in that answer. You should have

$$g(-4) = (-4)^2 - 4(-4) + 16$$

(not $+4(-4)$). This would give you $16 - (-16) + 16 = 16 + 16 + 16 = 48$. I believe that should be the right answer, if my own work is right.

Comment: You're correct! Thank you!